How to update Ssl_default_timeout on RDS MySQL?
I am trying to run long queries (like OPTIMIZE TABLE) and they time out automatically after 7200s, which is the current value for Ssl_default_timeout.
This parameter is not exposed in the parameter groups for RDS. Is there another way to change it?
